# SQL - Combine data from several columns into one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, union-all

I am creating complicated CTE Query. In MSSQL
Which result will be something like that

```
| Id1 | Id2 | Id3 |
|  1  |  2  |  3  |
|  5  |  4  |  1  |
|  6  |  5  |  2  |
```

And now I need to combine all data into on column something like that

```
| Ids |
|  1  |
|  2  |
|  3  |
|  5  |
|  4  |
|  1  |
|  6  |
|  5  |
|  2  |
```

I want to try avoid **union all** and select by each column
Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with `UNION ALL`? I'd go with it...

Comment: As I said this result will be from complicated CTE query and I think union all by every column will be not effective

Comment: If you like or not the simplest way  is  UNION ALL

Comment: I know but i am looking for different options of course if  any exists :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My favorite way of doing this uses `cross apply`:

```
select v.id
from t cross apply
     (values (t.id1), (t.id2), (t.id3)) v(id);
```

Like the version using `unpivot` this only reads the table once.  A version using `union all` would scan the table three times.  However, `cross apply` is much more powerful than `unpivot` and requires less typing.

Comment: This is not a ANSI standard solution ...rather product specific

Comment: @Rahul . . . There is support for lateral joins in the standard.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no different options other than usuing `UNION` operation. Basic purpose of `UNION` operation is that only ... combining records from multiple sources/result sets. So you can do like

```
select Id1 from tbl1
union
select Id3 from tbl1
union
select Id2 from tbl1
```

Comment: This answer is not correct.  Do you understand why?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, no .. enlighten me

Comment: @Rahul `union` removes duplicate results. `union all` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [UNPIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
SELECT Ids
FROM
(
    SELECT Id1, Id2, Id3
    FROM CTE
) d
UNPIVOT 
(
    Ids for id in (Id1, Id2, Id3) 
) u
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use UNPIVOT table to get your result :

CREATE TABLE #table( Id1 INT ,Id2 INT , Id3 INT )
INSERT INTO #table(  Id1 ,Id2 , Id3 ) 
SELECT 1 ,  2 ,  3 UNION ALL
SELECT 5 ,  4 ,  1 UNION ALL
SELECT 6 ,  5 ,  2 

SELECT _Result [Result]
FROM 
(
  SELECT Id1 ,Id2 , Id3
  FROM #table
)A
UNPIVOT
 (
  _Result FOR Id IN (Id1 , Id2 , Id3)
 ) UNPvt
```